# using mysql_fetch_array to print a comma seperated string and mysql_num to count

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am working on a project where I need to count the total number of comments on every particular post and also print the commenters id in a comma separated string.
Here is how I am taking the id of commenters and counting the comments

```
$commenters=mysql_query("select session_id from comments where onid='theid'");
$noof_comments=mysql_num_rows($commenters); //counting the comments working good
$forprintingid=mysql_fetch_array($commenters);/* now I know this array stores all the
 session ids of commenters and I can print them by using while loop but 
   here I do not want to use any loops ..*/
```

The output may look like

```
 total comments =$noof_comments // total comments=13
 commenters id= // it should be like 1,2,3,4,5,6,
```

and if any id is repeated just use them only once. 
Please help me. I am stuck over here may be implode is the 
function that may help but I dont know how exactly ...:(

Comment: mysql_fetch_array returns a SINGLE row of your result set. it doesn't return all of them. never has, never will. you need to fetch in a loop to get all of the selected values. after that your csv-conversion should be trivial.

Comment: is there any other way to fetch all the rows at once and then print it

Comment: no. not with the mysql_*() functions, which are obsolete/deprecated anyways. If you were using PDO or mysqli, then yes, you could.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing it fully in PHP, you can also check out `GROUP_CONCAT` function in `MySQL` which will give comma separated field values as you need.

`SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(field_name) FROM table_name...`

Comment: but the other function mysql_num_rows dosent works in this case

Comment: :) Well you cant have both. The first way means that you will get results as each row - which allows you to count, but you will have to concatenate if separately. The second way means that you will get the columns as comma separated but then naturally they will be a single row.

Comment: `$noof_comments = substr_count($forprintingid, ',') + 1;`

Comment: Good decision. I just threw in group_concat because in cases where you do not need the count, it is a really handy function that gets used very little!

Comment: @AbraCadaver - I thought of that, I just didn't want to get into that I always thought format-counting was kind of kludge... :)

Comment: Can't he still select group_concat() as concat, ids as id and do them both in one query?

Comment: @Adelphia - He most definitely can, I believe. But if it is not really a simple query, it can be a headache with HAVING clauses and all.

Answer (score 1):

```
$commenters=mysql_query("select session_id from comments where onid='theid'");
$noof_comments=mysql_num_rows($commenters); //counting the comments working good
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($commenters))
$forprintingid[]=$row[0];

echo implode(',', $forprintingid); //it shoul be like 1,2,3,4,5,6,
```

Comment: Will echo `1,1,2,2...`.  Check the fetch function.

Answer (score 1):

```
$r = array(); while($x = mysql_fetch_assoc($commenters)) $r[] = $x; $forprintingid = implode(",",$x);
```

one line of code :)
*edit* Does this still count as one line?

Comment: One line that implodes one column from one row with itself.

Comment: touche good sir.. guess there's no real way to avoid the loop.

Answer (score 1):

No matter what you'll need to loop.  Also, you only want either a numerically indexed or associative array.

You can create a function:

```
function mysql_fetch_all($result, $result_type = MYSQL_ASSOC) {
    while($rows[] = mysql_fetch_array($result, $result_type)) {} return $rows;
}
```

Then use `implode()` on the result array:

```
$forprintingid = implode(',', mysql_fetch_all($commenters));
```